# How to detect if user select cancel InputBox VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I have an input box asking user to enter a date. How do I let the program know to stop if the user click cancel or close the input dialog instead of press okay.

Something like
`if str=vbCancel then exit sub`

Currently, user can hit OK or Cancel but the program still runs

`str = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Date MM/DD/YYY", _
          Title:="Date Confirmation", Default:=Date)`
[image]

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If the user clicks Cancel, a zero-length string is returned. You can't differentiate this from entering an empty string. You can however make your own custom InputBox class...

**EDIT** to properly differentiate between empty string and cancel, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063938/832052).

Your example

```vb
Private Sub test()
    Dim result As String
    result = InputBox("Enter Date MM/DD/YYY", "Date Confirmation", Now)
    If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    ElseIf result = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox ("User didn't enter anything!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("User entered " & result)
    End If
End Sub
```

Would tell the user they canceled when they delete the default string, or they click cancel.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks - It should have been Vbnullstring instead of vbCancel

Comment: @DanVerdolino That is true if you use the declared String variable for the test. But as Siddharth has pointed out, you can use the button pushed as well.

Answer (score 3):

The solution above does not work in all InputBox-Cancel cases. Most notably, it does *not* work if you have to **InputBox** a **Range**.

For example, try the following InputBox for defining a custom range ('sRange', type:=8, requires Set + Application.InputBox) and you will get an error upon pressing Cancel:

```
Sub Cancel_Handler_WRONG()
Set sRange = Application.InputBox("Input custom range", _
    "Cancel-press test", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
If StrPtr(sRange) = 0 Then  'I also tried with sRange.address and vbNullString
    MsgBox ("Cancel pressed!")
    Exit Sub
End If
    MsgBox ("Your custom range is " & sRange.Address)
End Sub
```

The only thing that works, in this case, is an "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler" statement *before* the InputBox + ErrorHandler at the end:

```
Sub Cancel_Handler_OK()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set sRange = Application.InputBox("Input custom range", _
    "Cancel-press test", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
MsgBox ("Your custom range is " & sRange.Address)
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("Cancel pressed")
End Sub
```

So, the question is how to detect *either* an error *or* StrPtr()=0 with an **If** statement?

Comment: `StrPtr()=0` check will not work if you use `Application.InputBox`. In order for that to work, you need to use simply `InputBox`.

Comment: This solution confuses the Inputbox method `Application.Inputbox` with the Function `Inputbox`. The method returns `False` if the user presses cancel so the answer given is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Following example uses InputBox method to validate user entry to unhide sheets:
Important thing here is to use wrap InputBox variable inside StrPtr so it could be compared to '0' when user chose to click 'x' icon on the InputBox.

```
Sub unhidesheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pw As String

pw = InputBox("Enter Password to Unhide Sheets:", "Unhide Data Sheets")
If StrPtr(pw) = 0 Then

   Exit Sub
ElseIf pw = NullString Then
   Exit Sub
ElseIf pw = 123456 Then
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input box is an array, it does not work. I have solved it by adding a check for if it is an array first.

```
Dim MyArrayCheck As String
Dim MyPlateMapArray as variant
MyPlateMapArray = Application.InputBox("Select ....", Type:=8)

MyArrayCheck = IsArray(MyPlateMapArray)
If MyArrayCheck = "False" Then
Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with a False like below

```
MyLLOQ = Application.InputBox("Type the LLOQ number...", Title:="LLOQ to be inserted in colored cells.", Type:=1)
    If MyLLOQ = False Then Exit Sub
```

If user click cancel the sub will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion.

Create a message box when `inputbox` return null value. Example:

```
Dim PrC as string = MsgBox( _
"No data provided, do you want to cancel?", vbYesNo+vbQuestion, "Cancel?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub TestInputBox()
Dim text As String
text = InputBox("Type some text")
If text = "" Then
MsgBox "button cancel pressed or nothing typed"
Else
MsgBox text
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Inputbox send a boolean False value when Cancel is pressed.

contenidoy = Application.InputBox("Cantidad = ", titulox, contenidox, , , , , Type:=1)

'ESC or CANCEL

If contenidoy = False Then
MsgBox "Cancelado"
Else
MsgBox "Edición aceptada"
'End If

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).