# How to differentiate the action when a user hit CANCEL button or OK button under a Inputbox.

Tags: vba, excel

How to differentiate the action when a user hit CANCEL button or OK button under a Inputbox.

There are two scenarios:
1. To end (Exit Sub) the operation when user hit Cancel/Close button
2. If user hit OK without any value ask him to enter some value.

The code i use satisfy 2nd scenario, is it possible to accommodate 1st scenario as well?

```
Sub INPUT_BOX()

Re_Enter_Username:
cUsername = INPUTBOX("Username", "Please provide Login Name")
    If cUsername = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please provide a Username"
        GoTo Re_Enter_Username:
    Else 'Code if not empty
    End If

End Sub
```

I am not sure whether this is possible, may be my exception was more than what VBA can help provide. :) Sorry if so.

And thanks if you have a solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264814/how-to-detect-if-user-select-cancel-inputbox-vba-excel

Comment: Thanks braX, I went through that stackoverflow question, but that one doesn't satisfy my both the scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test using `StrPtr` like this:

```
cusername = InputBox("Username", "Please provide Login Name")
    If StrPtr(cusername) = 0 Then
        ' user pressed Cancel
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf cusername = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please provide a Username"
        GoTo Re_Enter_Username:
    Else 'Code if not empty
    End If
```